# How to swap images of list gridview(recyleview) in android

Tags: java

I have a list of images say 6. My requirement is to drag and drop the image. Say If i drag the image first with six then postion of six image become first and vice versa. Thanks for your support in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Let me explain. Actually I need to create a view of four image which is used for profile image. I just need to fetch the image through gallary or camera and user can able to drag and drop the image with each other or we can say that swap the images